# Angular Karma Jasmine TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'controls') at UserContext.apply app.componet.spec.ts

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

When I run the test I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'controls')`.

Why I can't access controls in my test file?

My function:

```
loadData() {
 if (this.rootForm.get(['name'])?.value &&
        this.rootForm.get(['address'])?.value) {
        this.signatureflag = true;
 }else {
  this.signatureflag = false
 }
 
 }
```

```
it('load data ',() =>{
     let fixture: ComponentFixture<ImportantMattersComponent>;
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ImportantMattersComponent);
     fixture.componentInstance.rootForm.controls.name.setValue('name');
     fixture.componentInstance.rootForm.controls.address.setValue('address');
     component.loadData();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test cases `SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS` should not load data when form fields are empty

```
it('load data ', () => {
    component.rootForm.controls.name.setValue('name');
    component.rootForm.controls.address.setValue('address');
    component.loadData();
    expect(component.signatureflag).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should not load data when form fields are empty', () => {
    component.rootForm.controls.name.setValue('');
    component.rootForm.controls.address.setValue('');
    component.loadData();
    expect(component.signatureflag).toBe(false);
  });
```

[Working Example - Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-unit-testing-ts67jm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fplayground-template-driven-forms-component%2Fplayground-template-driven-forms-component.component.spec.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Could you try running `fixture.detectChanges()` before accessing the form properties

[Documentation reference for fixture.detectChanges()](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#detectchanges)

```
it('load data ',() =>{
     let fixture: ComponentFixture<ImportantMattersComponent>;
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ImportantMattersComponent);
     component = fixture.componentInstance;
     fixture.detectChanges(); // <- changed here!
     component.rootForm.controls.name.setValue('name');
     component.rootForm.controls.address.setValue('address');
     component.loadData();
});
```

Usually we place the first three lines in a `beforeEach` block and then the remaining code runs in the `it` block, else you will repeat the same lines for each test case!

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'get')

Comment: I added first 3 lines in  beforeEach block and tried vice versa but error persist TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'get') –

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your form object **fixture.componentInstance.rootForm** is null while you are setting value to controls.
So Make sure your form object should be set with controls with blank values.
for ex:

```
 rootForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    address: new FormControl('')
  });
```

Either you can try this: add ? after rootForm.

```
      fixture.componentInstance.rootForm?.controls.name.setValue('name');
      fixture.componentInstance.rootForm?.controls.address.setValue('address');
```

Or put this 2 lines in settimeout function:

```
    setTimeout(()=>{                     
        fixture.componentInstance.rootForm.controls.name.setValue('name');
          fixture.componentInstance.rootForm.controls.address.setValue('address');
});
```